# Migrating MS-Project 2013 Master Schedule to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

The Master Schedule which I've been using on a Network Drive I've moved to SharePoint. So far it appears that if I also move the individual projects files to SharePoint and update the link it will work, however if I leave any individual projects files on the Network even though the link is accurate it appears not to be able to access them. Given our organization it would be better if we could work with the individual project files in both locations so that's my question here - can it be done and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

what you can try doing is mounting the SharePoint document library locally as a network file share.  Then when you open Project - point it at the file share instead of the URL in SharePoint directly.  This way, you should be able to keep the method for accessing the files consistently.